# Is there a good tool to debug Perl-based web applications?

Tags: perl, debugging

Is there a good tool to debug Perl-based web applications? Output to stderr or stdout don't count as tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup, I've got the perfect tool for you.

[CGI::Inspect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-Inspect/) lets you inspect and debug a running Perl web application.

Read more about [the module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Inspect) on the [developer's website](http://thelackthereof.org/CGI_Inspect).

Or check out the [slides from a presentation about it](http://thelackthereof.org/projects/perl/yapcna-2009/cgi-inspect/YAPCNA%202009%20-%20CGI%20Inspect.pdf) at YAPC::NA 2009.

Comment: CGI::Inspect is awesome.  It drops you into a REPL (read, eval, print, loop) where you can examine the current state of the app, modify the state, and they start it running again.

Comment: @Je Rog, I'm not sure -- there doesn't seem to be breakpoint support listed in the documentation.

Comment: so it's just an inspecter as its name ,nost a decent debugger.

Comment: This is only for CGI, not really a recommended way to develop Perl web anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The [Komodo](http://community.activestate.com/products/Komodo) IDE supports [remote debugging](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/debugperl.html) for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

The [EPIC plugin](http://www.epic-ide.org/) for Eclipse will also let you do this.

Answer (score 2):

In CGI, you can

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

It will display any fatal message in your browser.

With Mason, leave the default error option, which outputs the call stack in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not assume, [like the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199477/46235), that the module being used is [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI), but rather provide something that will work across anything that is supported by/supports [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org).

Perhaps combine [Plack::Middleware::Debug](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack-Middleware-Debug) (to display information about the active request and response, perhaps adding the [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack-Middleware-Debug-Log4perl) panel) and [Devel::hdb](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-hdb) to debug the running code in a separate tab.

Also available (I haven't tried it though) is [InteractiveDebugger](http://search.cpan.org/dist//Plack-Middleware-InteractiveDebugger)

Anything you try should be run in a single process, non-forking server like [HTTP::Server::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack/lib/HTTP/Server/PSGI.pm) or [HTTP::Server::Simple::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Server-Simple-PSGI) for development and debugging instead of something like [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Starman).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party on this one, but I felt some other tools should be called out in case anyone else stumbles upon this question.

The Perl command line debugger is perfectly serviceable, but occasionally hard to use, and has a fairly steep learning curve, especially for those who are used to GUI tools.

[Devel::hdb](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3ahdb) is a great tool for this. It integrates with the existing debugging functionality in Perl, so you can start the application with -d:hdb as a flag, and then you can hit a web based endpoint to start stepping through the application easily. It supports breakpoints, watch expressions, and stepping, so it can help you figure out where an issue is on a somewhat live application.

As mentioned earlier, ActiveState's [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (not Edit) has a built in graphical debugger, that can work on a local instance or against a remote server. The remote server must have some libraries installed, and activated within the code to work. It's not invasive, but it should be known. Also, Komodo costs money, but they do provide a trial period. It'll work on Windows, OS X or Linux. ActiveState's [Perl Dev Kit](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit) has an independent debugger as well, but I haven't used it in years.